# Ubiquity crashes during install

Tags: 12.04, ubiquity

So I have been trying to install 12.04 On my desktop since alpha 2 which is an old HP with 1 gig of RAM an AMD xp 2400+ and an nVidia geforce 5200 fx. The installer has always crashed at the same spot it crashes right as the slide show is supposed to start. and leaves my computer bricked. I figured it would be fixed by now for release but it hasn't. I REALLY want 12.04 just to use gnome classic but with new software.

Comment: Is this with the Live-CD Thomas? Have you tried the Alternate-CD?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: This needs to either be reported as a bug, but check to see that your CD was burned correctly, and check the md5sum of the ISO you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to run the installer from the command line and possibly disable the migration assistant (an application, which tries to move your documents from other OSs to the newly installed Ubuntu - I remember that in the past it has been a source of similar problems)

```
ubiquity --no-migration-assistant
```

Also, do not download the updates during the installation (to narrow down the problem). And see what happens, check the logs (most importantly `/var/log/syslog`) ... and search for their causes...